# Why isn't my JSP displaying in the German (de_DE) locale when I use <fmt:setLocale>?

Tags: jsp, jstl, locale, resourcebundle, setlocale

I've created the following JSP:

```
<!-- WebContent/pages/ResourceBundlesJST.jsp -->
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="hu.flux.locale.LanguageToolkit" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%  
    Locale locale = LanguageToolkit.getLanguage(request);
    //String locale = LanguageToolkit.getLanguageString(request);
%>
<fmt:setLocale value="${locale}" />
<fmt:bundle basename="hu.flux.locale.resources.TestResources">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><fmt:message key="greetHeading"/></h1>
        <p><fmt:message key="welcomeText"/></p>
        <p>Your locale is <%= locale %>.</p>
        <form action="your_form_handler_here" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="name"><fmt:message key="namePrompt"/></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="age"><fmt:message key="agePrompt"/></label>
                <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="place"><fmt:message key="placePrompt"/></label>
                <input type="text" id="place" name="place">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="submitButtonText"/>">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
</fmt:bundle>
```

When I try to visit the page with this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/SamsTeachYourselfJSP/pages/ResourceBundlesJSTL.jsp?languageOverride=de_DE
```

This is displayed to the screen:

```
Hello!

Welcome to our web site. Please take a moment to fill out our survey

Your locale is de_DE.

What is your name:  
How old are you:  
Where do you live:
```

The page is evidently finding and using the English properties file instead of the German one even though the server picked up my parameter to set the locale to de_DE and accepted the command to set the locale.

The resource I expect it to call contains:

```
# /src/hu/flux/locale/resources/TestResources_de.properties
namePrompt=Wie hei[gb]en Sie:
agePrompt=Wie alt sind Sie:
placePrompt=Wo wohnen Sie:
greetHeading=Guten Tag!
welcomeText= Willkommen bei unserer Web-Site.  Bitte, dauern Sie einen Moment Um unsere Umfrage auszufüllen
submitButtonText=Senden
```

I'm pretty sure the problem isn't in my LanguageToolkit class since that works fine with a non-JSTL version of this page, but if anyone wants to see it:

```
/**
 * /src/hu/flux/locale/LanguageToolkit.java
 */
package hu.flux.locale;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * @author Brian Kessler
 *
 */
public class LanguageToolkit {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public LanguageToolkit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static Locale getLanguage(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        // Get the browser's preferred language.
        String acceptLangString = request.getHeader("ACCEPT-LANGAUGE");

        // Allow the user to override the browser's langauge setting.
        // This lets you test with tools such as Babelfish 
        // (which isn't that great at translating to begin with).
        String override = request.getParameter ("languageOverride");
        if (override != null) { acceptLangString = override; }

        // If there is an ACCEPT-LANGUAGE header, parse it.
        if (acceptLangString != null) 
        {  
            Locale acceptedLocale = parseLangString (acceptLangString);
            if (acceptedLocale != null) {locale = acceptedLocale;}
        }

        return locale;
    }

    public static String getLanguageString(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String locale = "EN-uk";

        // Get the browser's preferred language.
        String acceptLangString = request.getHeader("ACCEPT-LANGAUGE");

        // Allow the user to override the browser's langauge setting.
        // This lets you test with tools such as Babelfish 
        // (which isn't that great at translating to begin with).
        String override = request.getParameter ("languageOverride");
        if (override != null) { acceptLangString = override; }

        // If there is an ACCEPT-LANGUAGE header, parse it.
        if (acceptLangString != null)  {locale = acceptLangString;}

        return locale;
    }

    private static Locale parseLangString(String acceptLangString) 
    {
        // The accepted languages should be separated by commas, but also
        // add space as a separator to eliminate whitespace.
        StringTokenizer localeParser = new StringTokenizer(acceptLangString, " ,");

        // See whether there is a language in the list (you need only the first one).
        if (localeParser.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            // Get the locale.
            String localeStr = localeParser.nextToken();

            // The local should be in the format ll-CC where 11 is the language
            // and CC is the country, like en-US for English in the U.S. and
            // de-DE for German in Germany.  Allow the browser to use _ instead
            // of -, too.
            StringTokenizer localeSplitter = new StringTokenizer (localeStr, "_-");

            // Assume both values are blank.
            String language = "";
            String country = "";

            // See whether a language is specified.
            if (localeSplitter.hasMoreTokens()) {language = localeSplitter.nextToken(); }

            // See whether a country is specified (there won't always be one).
            if (localeSplitter.hasMoreTokens()) {country = localeSplitter.nextToken(); }

            // Create a local based on this language and country (if country is blank,
            // you'll still get locale-based text, but currencies won't display correctly.
            return (new Locale(language, country));
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Any ideas why I am seeing English and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

First, the [`fmt:setLocale` TLDDOC](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/setLocale.html) says the following:

> `value` - `java.lang.String` - A **String** value is interpreted as the printable representation of a locale, which must contain a two-letter (lower-case) language code (as defined by ISO-639), and may contain a two-letter (upper-case) country code (as defined by ISO-3166). Language and country codes must be separated by hyphen (-) or underscore (_).

In other words, you can't set it with a `java.util.Locale`.

Second, anything which is been declared using *scriptlets* cannot be accessed in EL. EL can only access attributes which are been placed in `PageContext`, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpSession` or `ServletContext` by its `setAttribute()` method. Under the covers, EL basically does a [`pageContext.findAttribute(name)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) for a `${name}`. There are basically 4 solutions in order from least to best recommendation:

1. Use *scriptlet* instead of EL in `<fmt:setLocale>`.
2. Put the locale in request scope by `request.setAttribute("locale", locale);` inside *scriptlet*.
3. [Get rid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) of *scriptlets* and declare `LanguageToolkit` as an EL function.
4. Create a `Filter` which does the job.

---

That said, I would recommend to use [`<fmt:setBundle>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/setBundle.html) instead of `<fmt:bundle>` in this particular case since you seem want to cover the entire page. I would also recommend to use [`HttpServletRequest#getLocale()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale%28%29) instead of manually parsing the request header. The correct algorithm is more complex than what you've as far.

Comment: I don't really follow the above so well.  If I used <fmt:setLocal value="de_DE" />, I get the results I am looking for.  If I output the variable "locale" (with or without explicitly adding ".toString()", the value is "de_DE".  So, I don't see what the difference is.... and I'm not sure what you mean about using scriptlet(s), nor HttpServletRequest#getLocale()....  If you have time, can you please break that down for me?

Comment: I managed to make solution #2 work... would still be curious how to implement the other solutions, especially the better ones.  :-)

Comment: Scriptlets are those old fashioned `<% %>` things. EL is the modern `${}` things. They don't share the same variable scope. Click the "get rid" link to learn more.

Comment: Cheers for the clarification!